# Diffbot URL encode

Tags: java, diffbot

I got the problem with diffbot url encode problem.
I have a URL and I pass url when I call diffbot api like this.

```
//JsonNode json= (JsonNode)client.analyze(DiffbotClient.ResponseType.Jackson,url);
```

but I got error massage about url encoding.this is error message that I got

> {"errorCode":500,"error":"URL encoding"}

So I change my code system like this.

```
//JsonNode json= (JsonNode) client.analyze(DiffbotClient.ResponseType.Jackson,u.getHost()+u.getPath()+URLEncoder.encode("?"+u.getQuery(),"UTF-8"));
```

but it doesn't work out and `Diffbot` print like that

> {"errorCode":500,"error":"Error."}.

what kind of Encoding format diffbot `API` is using?

Comment: _"I got error message..."_ -- ***what error message?***  _"it doesn't work"_ -- ***HOW*** does it not work?  What happens?  Your question is not answerable in its present form.  Please [edit] your question to include the relevant information.

Comment: I got {"errorCode":500,"error":"Error."} error message from Diffbot. I also change in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're supposed to only encode the URL the contents of which you're processing with Diffbot, not the entire API string. For example, replace `{{token}}` below with your own and visit the URL in the browser. It will work.

Use this as inspiration to build your own URL for the API call:

```
http://api.diffbot.com/v3/article?token={{token}}&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sitepoint.com%2Fdiffbot-crawling-visual-machine-learning%2F
```

As you can see, only the `url` query param is encoded, and it's no special encoding, it's just basic HTML entity encoding.

Comment: http://api.diffbot.com/v3/article?token={{token}}&url=http://www.sitepoint.com/diffbot-crawling-visual-machine-learning/

I call with this URL. but it working too... I don't clear what you said about entire API.